# Timestamp values changing Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql

The timestamp when storing in database its correct but while querying it back the value of time is changing.

```
models.py
aed = models.CharField(max_length=100)
gbp = models.CharField(max_length=100)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= False,auto_now_add=True)
```

Database Stored Values

```
2018-01-10 13:17:05.107542+05:30
2018-01-10 13:18:01.803399+05:30
2018-01-10 13:19:01.873091+05:30
2018-01-10 13:20:04.476807+05:30
2018-01-10 13:21:01.913048+05:30
```

My query Values

```
2018-01-10 07:47:05.107542+00:00
2018-01-10 07:47:05
2018-01-10 07:49:01.873091+00:00
2018-01-10 07:49:01
2018-01-10 07:51:01.913048+00:00
2018-01-10 07:51:01
2018-01-10 07:48:01.803399+00:00
2018-01-10 07:48:01
2018-01-10 07:50:04.476807+00:00
2018-01-10 07:50:04
```

The Time is getting changed.

My Settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE =  'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Isn't this simply the timezone that is set to UTC, like you specify with `TIME_ZONE`? The database values are in the range `13:17+05:30`, and the others `07:47+0:00` which perfectly matches.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

> For `timestamp with time zone`, the **internally stored value is always in
>   UTC** (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean
>   Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is
>   converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If
>   no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be
>   in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is
>   converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.
>
> **When a timestamp with time zone value is output, it is always
>   converted from UTC to the current timezone zone, and displayed as
>   local time in that zone.**

formatting mine.

What you see is different client timezone zones - the one you use to query db directly uses `+05:30` and the django one - `UTC`